# How do I perform vector addition in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How do I perform vector addition in Ruby so that

```
[100, 100] + [2, 3]
```

yields

```
[102, 103]
```

(instead of joining two arrays)?

Or it can be another operator too, such as

```
[100, 100] @ [2, 3]
```

or

```
[100, 100] & [2, 3]
```

Comment: If this were lisp, the solution would be to use map: (map + '(100 100) '(2 3)) => (102 103). Maybe Ruby has a similar function?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

See the [Vector](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html) class:

```
require "matrix"

x = Vector[100, 100]
y = Vector[2, 3]
print x + y

E:\Home> ruby t.rb
Vector[102, 103]
```

See [vectorops](https://github.com/psorowka/vectorops) for additional operations on vectors:

> … the following operations work like expected

```
  v1 = Vector[1,1,1,0,0,0]
  v2 = Vector[1,1,1,1,1,1]

  v1[0..3]
  # -> Vector[1,1,1]

  v1 += v2
  # -> v1 == Vector[2,2,2,1,1,1]

  v1[0..3] += v2[0..3]
  # -> v1 == Vector[2,2,2,0,0,0]

  v1 + 2
  # -> Vector[3,3,3,1,1,1]
```

See also [vectorops](https://github.com/psorowka/vectorops).

Note that [matrix is no longer a default gem](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2021/12/25/ruby-3-1-0-released/) starting with Ruby 3.1.0. Thanks to [Dan Murphy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3826560/dan-murphy-boulder) for mentioning this.

Comment: Heads up that Matrix was removed from the standard lib in Ruby 3.1, see this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71991514/rails-require-cannot-load-such-file-matrix

Answer (score 19):

Array#zip:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> [100,100].zip([2,3]).map { |e| e.first + e.last }
=> [102, 103]
```

Shorter:

```
irb(main):002:0> [100,100].zip([2,3]).map { |x,y| x + y }
=> [102, 103]
```

Generalized to >2 dimensions with #inject:

```
irb(main):003:0> [100,100,100].zip([2,3,4]).map { |z| z.inject(&:+) }
=> [102, 103, 104]
```

Answer (score 3):

Or if you want arbitrary dimension behavior of that variety (like mathematical vector addition)

```
 class Vector < Array
   def +(other)
     case other
     when Array
       raise "Incorrect Dimensions" unless self.size == other.size
       other = other.dup
       self.class.new(map{|i| i + other.shift})
     else
       super
     end
   end
 end

class Array
  def to_vector
    Vector.new(self)
  end
end 

[100,100].to_vector + [2,3] #=> [102,103]
```

The lack of a lisp style map is quite obnoxious.

Answer (score 3):

When in Rome..monkeypatch.

```
module Enumerable
  def sum
    inject &:+
  end

  def vector_add(*others)
    zip(*others).collect &:sum
  end
end
```

Then you can do a.vector_add(b) and it works.  I believe this requires Ruby 1.8.7, or an extension that adds Symbol.to_proc.  You can also add an arbitrary number of vectors this way.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a sidenote, if you (like me) felt unsatisfied with the operations that are provided by the default Vector class from ruby, consider giving my gem https://github.com/psorowka/vectorops a look, which adds some functionality I would expect from a proper Vector implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
module PixelAddition
  def +(other)
    zip(other).map {|num| num[0]+num[1]}
  end
end
```

Then you can either create an Array subclass that mixes in the module, or add the behavior to specific arrays like:

```
class <<an_array
  include PixelAddition
end
```

Comment: Great use of modules, but having some instances of Array interpret the + operator in a different way than other instances really scares me. You might even get situations where (a + b) != (b + a).