# ruby: sum corresponding members of two or more arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, sum

I've got two (or more) arrays with 12 integers in each (corresponding to values for each month). All I want is to add them together so that I've got a single array with summed values for each month. Here's an example with three values:
[1,2,3] and [4,5,6] => [5,7,9]

The best I could come up with was:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]].transpose.map{|arr| arr.inject{|sum, element| sum+element}} #=> [5,7,9]
```

Is there a better way of doing this? It just seems such a basic thing to want to do.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here's the `transpose` version Anurag suggested:

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]].transpose.map {|x| x.reduce(:+)}
```

This will work with any number of component arrays. `reduce` and `inject` are synonyms, but `reduce` seems to me to more clearly communicate the code's intent here...

Comment: ... or in rails: a.transpose.map {|x| x.sum}

Comment: @jjnevis: well, if we're golfing it, how about `a.transpose.map(&:sum)`

Comment: @rampion: That's certainly quite terse - could you explain the (&:sum) bit? Thanks

Comment: @jjnevis: So, `Symbol#to_proc` returns a `Proc` that passes that symbol to its argument (so `:sum.to_proc` returns `lambda {|x| x.sum}`).  An `&` prefix-operator for the last argument to a method invokes `#to_proc` on the argument, and passes the resulting `Proc` as a block to the method.  This allows you to write methods that capture their block arguments (`def foo(a,b,&block)...end`) and pass them into whatever methods they may call (`bar = baz(1, &block)`).  It also allows this trickery with symbols, since `a.transpose.map(&:sum)` is the equivalent of your rails solution.

Comment: But note that in 1.9 `reduce` takes a symbol directly, thus the `:+` there instead of needing `&:+`...

Comment: @jjnevis It works for me outside rails in ruby 2.4.0p0

Answer (score 18):

Now we can use [sum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) in 2.4

```
nums = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
nums.transpose.map(&:sum) #=> [5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 11):

For clearer syntax (not the fastest), you can make use of `Vector`:

```
require 'matrix'
Vector[1,2,3] + Vector[4,5,6]
=> Vector[5, 7, 9]
```

For multiple vectors, you can do:

```
arr = [ Vector[1,2,3], Vector[4,5,6], Vector[7,8,9] ]
arr.inject(&:+)
=> Vector[12, 15, 18]
```

If you wish to load your arrays into Vectors and sum:

```
arrays = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]
arrays.map { |a| Vector[*a] }.inject(:+)
=> Vector[12, 15, 18]
```

Comment: This is definitely the cleanest from an understandability perspective.

Comment: To convert an array to a vector, you can also do `Vector.elements([1, 2, 3])`, in addition to `Vector[*a]`.

Answer (score 8):

here's my attempt at code-golfing this thing:

```
// ruby 1.9 syntax, too bad they didn't add a sum() function afaik
[1,2,3].zip([4,5,6]).map {|a| a.inject(:+)} # [5,7,9]
```

`zip` returns `[1,4]`, `[2,5]`, `[3,6]`, and map sums each sub-array.

Comment: Nice. How would this work with three or more arrays - I'm iterating over an unknown number of arrays, so the transpose works well because I can just push them into an empty array and transpose that. I love the ':+' syntax for inject (although not as good as a sum() method as you say, rails does add it, though)- not see that before, thanks.

Comment: zip is a method of Array, and it accepts any number of arrays as parameters. But I don't know how would you pass those if they were created dynamically. `transpose` seems like a better choice for that. Ruby generally covers many of the commonly used functions, but where is lacks, Rails comes to rescue!

Comment: say `aoa` is our array of arrays, and you want to calculate `[ aoa[0][0] + aoa[1][0] + ... + aoa[-1][0], aoa[0][1] + aoa[1][1] + ... + aoa[-1][1], ..., aoa[0][-1] + aoa[1][-1] + ... + aoa[-1][-1] ]` then you could do `first, *rest = *aoa; first.zip(*rest).map { |a| a.inject(&:+) }`

Comment: I think that `arr.zip(arr).map { |a,b| a + b }` is more readable than using inject/reduce over a 2 element array.

Answer (score 8):

I humbly feel that the other answers I see are so complex that they would be confusing to code reviewers. You would need to add an explanatory comment, which just increases the amount of text needed.

How about this instead:

```
a_arr = [1,2,3]
b_arr = [4,5,6]
(0..2).map{ |i| a_arr[i] + b_arr[i] }
```

Slightly different solution: (so that you're not hard coding the "2")

```
a_arr = [1,2,3]
b_arr = [4,5,6]
c_arr = []
a_arr.each_index { |i| c_arr[i] = a_arr[i] + b_arr[i] }
```

Finally, mathematically speaking, this is the same question as this:

[How do I perform vector addition in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009280/how-do-i-perform-vector-addition-in-ruby)

Answer (score 6):

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]].transpose.map{|a| a.sum} #=> [5,7,9]
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work in plain Ruby. Maybe it does in Rails, [as suggested by jjnevis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682411/ruby-sum-corresponding-members-of-two-arrays#comment2702699_2682983).

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wondering what the fastest solution is, these are the times for the answers being run 1,000,000 times each with Benchmark.bmbm

```
# plain-ole
a[0] += b[0]
a[1] += b[1]
a[2] += b[2]
a
```

```
# each_index
a.each_index { |i| a[i] += b[i] }
```

```
#zip-sum
a.zip(b).map(&:sum)
```

```
# transpose-sum
[a, b].transpose.map(&:sum)
```

```
#map
a.map.with_index { |v, i| v + b[i] }
```

```
# zip-reduce
a.zip(b).map { _1.reduce(&:+) }
```

```
# transpose-reduce
[a, b].transpose.map { _1.reduce(&:+) }
```

```
# vector-declared
Vector[1, 2, 3] + Vector[4, 5, 6]
```

```
# vector
Vector.elements(a) + Vector.elements(b)
```

```
Rehearsal ------------------------------------------------------
plain-ole            0.217787   0.000722   0.218509 (  0.218544)
each_index           0.431834   0.001533   0.433367 (  0.433421)
zip-sum              0.576384   0.002875   0.579259 (  0.579365)
transpose-sum        0.588562   0.002788   0.591350 (  0.591382)
map                  0.774294   0.002759   0.777053 (  0.777108)
zip-reduce           1.217026   0.005008   1.222034 (  1.222105)
transpose-reduce     1.244968   0.005115   1.250083 (  1.250596)
vector-initialized   1.691190   0.004128   1.695318 (  1.695422)
vector               1.972912   0.005582   1.978494 (  1.978689)
--------------------------------------------- total: 8.745467sec

                         user     system      total        real
plain-ole            0.215911   0.000831   0.216742 (  0.216781)
each_index           0.430009   0.001125   0.431134 (  0.431200)
zip-sum              0.567621   0.002756   0.570377 (  0.570465)
transpose-sum        0.589709   0.002606   0.592315 (  0.592342)
map                  0.769459   0.002611   0.772070 (  0.772167)
zip-reduce           1.209870   0.004881   1.214751 (  1.214985)
transpose-reduce     1.230031   0.004926   1.234957 (  1.235065)
vector-initialized   1.687652   0.003992   1.691644 (  1.691750)
vector               1.974240   0.005038   1.979278 (  1.979393)
```

Comment: Are there any novel solutions to the question here? It doesn't appear so.

Comment: No, but when I looked up this question and saw all the proposed solutions I was wondering how they compared speed wise, so I ran the tests and I figured it would be helpful for others who might run the test as I did.

Answer (score 1):

@FriendFX, you are correct about @user2061694 answer. It only worked in Rails environment for me. You can make it run in plain Ruby if you make the following changes...

In the IRB

```
[[0, 0, 0], [2, 2, 1], [1,3,4]].transpose.map {|a| a.inject(:+)}
 => [3, 5, 5]


[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]].transpose.map {|a| a.inject(:+)}
 => [5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

For:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
```

You could `zip` and then use `reduce`:

```
p a.zip(b).map{|v| v.reduce(:+) }
#=> [5, 7, 9]
```

Or, if you're sure that array `a` and `b` will always be of equal length:

```
p a.map.with_index { |v, i| v + b[i] }
#=> [5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Two very elegant solutions, although I've updated the title to more accurately reflect the question, namely that it's "two or more" arrays, so an array or arrays really.

Comment: A more succinct solution is ` a.zip(b).map(&:sum)`

Comment: @PereJoanMartorell : Sorry that you had to find out this way, but the `sum` method did not exist in Ruby when this was posted.

Comment: @Surya thanks for the explanation, maybe it would be helpful to offer a solution for different ruby versions so everyone can pick the one that fits better

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best answer but it works.

```
array_one = [1,2,3]
array_two = [4,5,6]
x = 0
array_three = []
while x < array_one.length
  array_three[x] = array_one[x] + array_two[x]
  x += 1
end

=>[5,7,9]
```

This might be more lines of code than other answers, but it is an answer nonetheless

Comment: I like this one simply because it's very clear what's going on, but you can clean it up a bit by using "array_one.each_index do |x|"

Comment: this is not very idiomatic Ruby. Using `while` loops is *very* rare