# Rails `require': cannot load such file -- matrix

Tags: matrix, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-7

after updating to ruby 3.1.2 and Rails 7.0.2.3

getting following error while starting rails application:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- matrix (LoadError)
```

what could be the possible solution, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Matrix was removed from Ruby's standard library in version 3.1. More info: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2021/12/25/ruby-3-1-0-released/

With Ruby 3.1, matrix needs to be explicitly added to the Gemfile. You can add it manually or run something like:

```
$ bundle add matrix
```

After it's added to the Gemfile, bundle your application:

```
$ bundle install
```

Then your application should continue to behave like it did in previous Ruby versions.

Comment: Solution for downgrading combine_pdf from 1.0.22 to 1.0.20. https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf/issues/205

Answer (score 11):

same here, **ruby 3.1.2, rails 7.0.4** after adding `prawn` to gemfile. I had to add `gem 'matrix'` to gemfile and it works.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me too, also `prawn` and `prawn-table` specific

Answer (score 9):

I came onto this issue as well when upgrading **Rails 6->7** and **Ruby 3.0.0->3.1.2**.

For my case the issue was related to Capybara gem. Version `3.35.3` assumed it is installed by default with Ruby.
When I upgraded the Capybara to version `3.37.1` then matrix gem was automatically installed as well and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 4):

Just ran into the same issue after adding **rubystats** gem for some seed data, also using ruby 3.1.2 and rails 7.0.4.

@siasmj 's fix worked for me.